# iron-router not waiting on meteor.user() to return

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

**Solved but looking for improvements, see answers**

```
    function completedProfile() {
        if (Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile.primary_email && Meteor.user().profile.display_name && Meteor.user().university_id) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    Router.map(function() {
        this.route('landing', {
            path: '/', // match the root path
            onBeforeAction: function() {
                this.subscribe('users').wait();
                if (this.ready() && completedProfile()) {
                    this.render('bulletin')
                } else {
                    this.redirect('splash');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

The page will redirect to my splash template since the completeProfile function is false (all fields are null in if statement).

Attempt 2 (hangs on splash after fields have been populated):

```
    Router.map(function() {
        this.route('landing', {
            path: '/', // match the root path
            action: function() {
                if (this.ready() && completedProfile()) {
                    this.redirect('bulletin')
                } else {
                    this.render('splash');
                }
            },
        });
```

**Attempt 3:**

```
    function completedProfile() {
        if (Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile.primary_email && Meteor.user().profile.display_name && Meteor.user().profile.university_id) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    Router.map(function() {
                this.route('landing', {
                    path: '/', // match the root path
                    action: function() {
                        console.log(Meteor.user().profile);  //this fails
                        console.log(this.ready(), completedProfile()); //this then returns as expected
                        if (this.ready() && !completedProfile()) {
                            this.redirect('splash');
                        } else {
                            this.render('bulletin')
                        }
                    },
                });

                this.route('splash', {
                    path: '/splash', // match the root path
                });

                this.route('bulletin', {
                    path: '/bulletin', // match the root path
                });
```

It's really weird that this works. The log of Meteor.user results in an error and *then* Meteor.user() loads giving me an appropriate completedProfile() return. The error is `Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined`
 .

Comment: `console.log(Meteor.user().profile);` throws an error when `Meteor.user()` returns `undefined` (you're trying to read the property `'profile'` of `undefined`). Try `if (Meteor.user()) { console.log(Meteor.user().profile) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are redirecting to a route named `splash`. You didn't include it, but I'll assume it exists. Once you've redirected, you're done with any logic for the `landing` route, so `completedProfile()` won't be re-run once a user is logged in.

Try this instead: stay on the `landing` route, but `render()` a splash page until the user is logged in.

```
if (this.ready() && completedProfile()) {
    this.render('bulletin')
} else {
    this.render('splash');
}
```

I don't think `this.subscribe('users').wait();` helps. I'd remove it. I think you also want to use `action` instead of `onBeforeAction` since you are calling `render()` yourself.

See also: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/91. Sounds like [instant login](https://meteorhacks.com/instant-login-for-meteor-with-fast-render.html) would work well for your use case.

Comment: If I do `if(ready && complete) redirect(bulletin) else render(splash)` it still hangs on the splash page (this is all under action). I'll take a look at instant login now.

Comment: Are you sure the `stop()` is what makes it work? I think changing `redirect()` to `render()` is what makes it work, because you stay on the `landing` route and it reacts (re-renders).

Comment: If I remove stop as soon as the user completes the profile field it'll redirect to bulletin, being reactive and what not. I have a complete/proceed button on the splash page that I want them to hit so they can review the info.

Answer (score 1):

Current working solution:

```
    function completedProfile() {
        if (Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile.primary_email && Meteor.user().profile.display_name  && Meteor.user().profile.university_id) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    }

    Router.map(function() {
        this.route('landing', {
            path: '/', // match the root path
            action: function() {
                if (this.ready()) {
                    if (!completedProfile()) {
                        this.render('splash');
                        this.stop();
                    } else {
                        this.render('bulletin')
                    }
                }    
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: When they fill out the profile the completedProfile will switch to true, rendering bulletin. The stop makes it so I can save all answers on completion and have it not redirect while they do the optional stuff.

Comment: This is what I recommended. Will you accept my answer? Or would you like me to improve it? Also: it would be easier to collaborate on code if you would create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) or repo (on github, gitlab, etc.).